# Data Transfer causes sharp edges in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normals

[image]

I'm using a data transfer modifier on an object, and its causing these jagged shadows on the mesh in the render view. This isn't happening in the viewport. I'm using blender 3.4, and rendering in cycles. Changing the autosmooth angle degree doesn't fix this, and neither does applying the transfer node. Adding custom split normals data doesn't affect this either. I've also tried subdividing the data transfer target object, and that doesn't change anything. not sure what else to try. I'm using a multires modifier in this image, but removing it also doesn't do anyhting. any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be sure, is it a node or a modifier?

Comment: it's a modifier. sorry for the confusion

Comment: What do you transfer with this Data Transfer modifier ?

Comment: @Hadriscus I transfered object normal data

Comment: 1. what is the source object, what does it look like?
2. to what end do you transfer normals?
3. why do it through the modifier and not destructively (=with the data transfer operator)?